# Star Trek episode referring to reversing the polarity of the Neutron flow?

Tags: story-identification, star-trek, technology

I want to remind myself how and when the polarity of the Neutron flow is reversed... in Star Trek :-)

That is, I'm asking in which episodes of Star Trek someone does someone suggest they "reverse the polarity of the neutron flow", or some sentence close enough to that one.

(I'm guessing this only happens in TNG but not sure even about that.)

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReversePolarity

Comment: @Richard: Make that an answer?

Comment: _You_? I'd say you cannot :P But seriously, since Neutrons are electrically neutral, this is indeed a, shall we say, curious endeavour...

Comment: Even though neutrons are electrically *neutral* they DO have a magnetic moment. So, you could actually inverting the polarity of a neutron flow, at least magnetically.

Comment: Ok, but that's not really my question...

Comment: @einpoklum I think your title is confusing and will lead to answers like these.

Comment: @Moogle: Clarified it a bit.

Comment: You can certainly reverse the polarity of the *flow*.

Comment: @FrancisDavey: You're thinking about reversing the _direction_ of the flow. Calling it the polarity is stretching the semantics too much, I think.

Comment: @einpoklum When I first saw The Three Doctors I parsed it as "reverse the polarity of the (neutron) flow". Certainly works in my dialect of English. Polarity of a flow seems to be a concept fairly widely used in the sciences, see eg http://geology.gsapubs.org/content/33/1/e87.full (used of water flow).

Comment: After all the momentum 1-form reverses polarity :-).

Comment: I'm assuming that in this case, polarity refers to the direction particles move, as it does in modern direct current cables. In this case, it would mean moving the neutrons in the opposite direction. As to how this could be achieved, the federation almost certainly has technology to move neutrons "for obvious reasons". This could be achieved by plugging the cables into opposite ports, like swapping an input and output port. The only issue this leaves is how they could move neutrons. Neutrons are overall neutrally charged, but internally, they are unbalanced, with positive and negative areas. T

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you may be confusing Star Trek for Doctor Who. The phrase "reverse the polarity of the Neutron flow" is something of a catchphrase of the [Third Doctor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_Doctor)...

To the best of my knowledge, a whole lot of things get their polarities reversed in Star Trek (including [shields](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shield_polarity), [magnetic constrictors](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReversePolarity), [magnetic probes](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Magnetic_probe), etc) but never a neutron flow.

Answer (score 25):

If you're sure it's Star Trek, there is one case of all the "reverse the polarity"s that contains all the pieces, and yet never uses the phrase.  The scene it occurs in also popped into my mind upon reading the question, but because the phrase is never used it took a while to find.

In TOS 3x14, [That Which Survives](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/That_Which_Survives_(episode)) the magnetic seal on the fuel flow is ruptured.  (A few minutes later, Scotty also refers to it as a "magnetic flow".  However, we know from later series that the "fuel" is actually antimatter, [which could be neutrons](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Antimatter#Background) (and yes, [antineutrons exist!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antineutron)))

Scotty goes into the "service crawlway" (also known as a [Jefferies tube](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Jefferies_tube)) in order to seal the rupture, during which time Spock performs an analysis on the ship to try and figure out why the ship felt different to Scotty.

The results are that the Enterprise was reassembled by a molecular transporter slightly out-of-phase, and Spock tells Scotty that "reverse polarity should seal the incision".

The specific image that came to mind upon reading the question was this scene:

[image: Scotty sealing the magnetic rupture with a reverse-polarity tool]

So yes, Scotty *reversed the polarity* of that tool in order to seal the rupture on the fuel/antimatter/possibly antineutron *flow*.

Comment: I'd +2 you if I could...

Comment: This is a bit of a reach. You can have a +1 for effort :-)

Answer (score 7):

There is another case of "*reversing the polarity*" in [TOS: Who Mourns for Adonais](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/33.htm). Said before Pertwee ever did!

> **SPOCK:** *Ready to reverse polarity, Mister Sulu?*
>
> **SULU:** *Computed and standing by to generate, sir.*
>
> **SPOCK:** *Activate all units.*

Comment: Weclome to SFF.SE! Great find!